# change lodash groupby key for undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, lodash

so i am working at making table row grouping using lodash groupby function and it works just fine by making this

```
var value = _.groupBy(itemData, groupkey)
```

so it will turn this raw data from api

```
itemData = {
  0: {
         name: 'article 1',
         category: 'news'
     },
  1: {
         name: 'article 2',
         category: 'lifestyle'
     },
  2: {
         name: 'article 3',
         category: 'news'
     }
}
```

to be like this

```
itemData = {
  news: 
     0: {
         name: 'article 1',
         category: 'news'
        },
     1: {
         name: 'article 3',
         category: 'news'
        }
  lifesyle:  
     0: {
         name: 'article 2',
         category: 'lifestyle'
     }
}
```

but when i have data api with no category data in database so  it returned null or undefined, then it will be showing like this

```
itemData = {
  undefined: 
     0: {
         name: 'article 1',
         category: undefined
        },
     1: {
         name: 'article 3',
         category: undefined
        }
  lifesyle:  
     0: {
         name: 'article 2',
         category: 'lifestyle'
     }
}
```

so how to catch those undefined and change it to other word? like say change it into "uncategorized" or "other"?

**update**

okay, first of all i'm sorry i thought doing this will be the same when using vanila javascript and vue js... the truth is i am using this in vue js environment... and when i tried all of your answer i got a very different result

so in vue the code will be like this: i am calling this grouping in computed property

```
computer:{
 groupData(){
  retun _.groupBy(this.itemData.data, this.group.key);
 }
}
```

**update 2**
so after seeing my raw data from api, i am using laravel eloquent relationship in the backend code so it will return this kind of api

```
itemData = {
 0: {
      name: 'article 1',
      category_id : 1,
      category__article: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'news'
      }
    }
 1: {
      name: 'article 2',
      category_id : 2,
      category__article: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'lifestyle'
      }
    }
 2: {
      name: 'article 3',
      category_id : '',
      category__article: undefined
    }
}
```

and what inside `this.group.key` is `category__article.name`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will do

```
 const groupData = _.groupBy(itemData, item => {
   return _.get(item, 'category__article.name', 'no_category');
 });
```

Using _.get to fetch nested value (item.category__article.name) and give default value (no_category) if the value is undefined.

[_.get Documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#get)

```js
const itemData = {
 0: {
      name: 'article 1',
      category_id : 1,
      category__article: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'news'
      }
    },
 1: {
      name: 'article 2',
      category_id : 2,
      category__article: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'lifestyle'
      }
    },
 2: {
      name: 'article 3',
      category_id : '',
      category__article: undefined
    }
}

const groupData = _.groupBy(itemData, item => _.get(item, 'category__article.name', 'no_category'));

console.log('groupData', groupData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Lodash [groupBy method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#groupBy) can accept a function as a parameter. So you can default the category value to 'other' as easy as this:

```js
const itemData = {
  0: {
    name: "article 1",
    category: "news"
  },
  1: {
    name: "article 2",
    category: undefined
  },
  2: {
    name: "article 3",
    category: null
  }
};

const groupkey = "category";
const defaultCategory = "other";

var value = _.groupBy(itemData, item => {
  const value = item[groupkey];

  if (!value) {
    return defaultCategory;
  }

  return value;
});

/*
Returns: 
{
  news: [{ name: "article 1", category: "news" }],
  other: [
    { name: "article 2", category: undefined },
    { name: "article 3", category: null }
  ]
}
*/
```

Comment: @LaurensiusTony It works as expected for me. Please see http://jsbin.com/nananebuzo/edit?js,console Could you try to reproduce your case in jsbin and share the link? Also please make sure that you're using the latest version of lodash.

Comment: @LaurensiusTony Not sure vue specifics could break the logic here. I'd advice you to do a breakpoint in you vue app, dump the variables and try running the data transformation. I think it's more likely that something's wrong with data structure.

Comment: @LaurensiusTony Please check this out :) http://jsbin.com/vupagesixi/1/edit?js,console

Comment: still got the same result... i don't know which one is wrong... https://paste.laravel.io/8688da2b-373e-411b-89f7-6c67fe00ebe6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165700/discussion-between-antonio-narkevich-and-laurensius-tony).

Answer (score 0):

comparing the value directly, or (!t)

```
  if (t === undefined) {
     return 'Undefined value!';
  }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Answer (score 0):

You could first `mapValues` to change category value from null or undefined to `uncategorized` and then use `groupBy` on that new object.

```js
const itemData = {0: {name: 'article 1',category: undefined},1: {name: 'article 2',category: null},2: {name: 'article 3', category: 'news'}}

const result = _.chain(itemData)
  .mapValues(o => {
    const category = 'uncategorized'
    return _.assign({}, o, !o.category && {category})
  }).groupBy('category').value()

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: its weird i get value like __action__ , __chain__ , etc... very weird

Comment: I am not sure what is the issue, `this.group.key` just needs to be key you want to group by.

Comment: yea i already changed into that and it supposed to be working but what i get is still undefined category

Comment: Maybe `this.itemData.data` should just be `this.itemData`

Comment: no, it must be this.itemData.data to make it work.... i do it right this... am i missing something? https://paste.laravel.io/2433e6c9-7fa2-400b-b9b8-dd70869529eb

Comment: With that data code should be like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/3027/